# Is there a back-"button" in w3m?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, w3m

Does w3m offer a keyboard shortcut to go back one page? I couldn't find anything in the man pages.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's `B` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>). It's the shortcut for `previous buffer` in `w3m` jargon.

See the [Manual](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/MANUAL) or a short introduction [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/103574/how-to-browse-from-the-linux-terminal-with-w3m/).

Comment: The keyboard shortcuts can be found in /usr/share/doc/w3m-0.5.2/doc/MANUAL.html (or where ever your w3m is installed).

Comment: Within w3m, press `H` to show the list of key bindings.

Comment: Related question: How could I assign `F` to going forward?

Answer (score 4):

the default **Shift-b** actually closes the current buffer so you can't go forward in history again. You can instead map your own hotkeys. e.g using **H** and **L** to go back and fort in the current buffers history

```
$EDITOR ~/.w3m/keymap

############################ Switch to the next buffer (NEXT)
keymap  L       NEXT
############################ Switch to the previous buffer (PREV)
keymap  H       PREV
```

Answer (score 2):

w3m keeps each page in a buffer, press s to see a list of buffers. This allows you to select the previous, it has the benefit of not closing the current buffer (unlike B).

Unrelated but I've just discovered that *Insert* brings up a useful menu, including s for select buffer.