# How to open several local (HTML) documents in lynx?

Tags: lynx

I was planning to use `lynx` for reading all local HTML files in a folder:

```
lynx ~/Documents/webpages/*
```

I don't know how to move beyond the first document. Quitting with `qq` exits the program and returns to the shell.

Specifying the directory (`lynx ~/Documents/webpages/`) requires manually selecting each entry (but `lynx` at least remembers the last one, when going back).

**note**: lynx doesn't support tabs and there's no need to open the pages at once.

Answer (score 3):

In Lynx,

- you can get to the other files by pressing <kbd>`g`</kbd>, and then using up/down cursor keys to scroll through the list of files.
- After you have visited a file, it is put into another list, which you can see using a double-<kbd>*tab*</kbd> after pressing <kbd>`g`</kbd> (and select by moving the cursor up/down, pressing <kbd>*Enter*</kbd>).
- Both are different from Lynx's *history-stack* (which you can inspect by pressing <kbd>*control*-`H`</kbd>).

This is not a new feature.  It is mentioned in the changelog for [2.8.3dev.1](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/current/CHANGES.html#v2.8.3dev.1) (1996/06/11):

> - Additional non-option args (before the last one), i.e.  URLs or filenames, are made available for 'g'oto recall.  If unwanted, this can be disabled by changing **`EXTENDED_STARTFILE_RECALL`** in LYMain.c -KW

w3m puts extra parameters into its history-stack and that should allow one to move to different files.

links/links2/elinks do not appear to support that feature at all.

Comment: In w3m the HTML files get indeed added to the history. Can move between entries by [mapping custom hotkeys](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/606731/172800).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have multiple pages to be open simultaneously. If you run `lynx` with multiple URLs in command line - it will open the last one.

It is however possible to create a *jump file*. It is virtually the same as bookmarks in other browsers.
Create a file with full URLs:

```
<dt>?<dd><a href="file://localhost/home/me/jumps.html">jumps file</a>
<dt>a<dd><a href="file://localhost/home/me/a.html">a file</a>
<dt>b<dd><a href="file://localhost/home/me/b.html">b file</a>
<dt>c<dd><a href="file://localhost/home/me/c.html">c file</a>
```

Please note, that the '?' have to be the first one in the file. Not sure why it is so...

Create/modify a local config file and add that jump file into it:

```
JUMPFILE:/home/me/jumps.html
INCLUDE:/etc/lynx/lynx.cfg
```

Next, enable that local config file on the `lynx` start

```
linx -cfg /home/me/lynx.cfg
```

Now all you need is to hit `j`, type the shortcut (the one defined in *dt*) and lynx will jump to that file.

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` can be used used to sequentially open HTML documents in `lynx` (`realpath` returns the absolute path):

```
realpath ~/Documents/webpages/*.html | xargs --max-lines=1 lynx
```